# SQLAlchemy session add: another instance is already present

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, orm

While having practice with SQLAlchemy 2.0 faced with behaviour that I can't understand.

```bash
# got from db
>>> student1 = session.execute(...)
>>> ex1 = session.execute(...)
>>> ex2 = session.execute(...)

# new objects
>>> hw1 = Homework(student=student1)
>>> t1 = Task(exercise=ex1, homework=hw1)
>>> t2 = Task(exercise=ex2, homework=hw1)

>>> session.add(hw1)
...
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't attach instance <Task at 0x1d9f9df8750>; another instance with key (<class 'model.orm.Task'>, (1,), None) is already present in this session.
```

Here are my models. What is so wrong with it, that I did get the exception above?
I think if it might be related to cascade behaviour on relationship() constructs? However [cascades doc page](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/cascades.html) didn't ever mention such exception.

```py
class Student(abstract.Base, abstract.Model):
    id = mapped_column(sqltypes.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    ...
    homeworks = relationship('Homework', back_populates='student', lazy='selectin')

class Homework(abstract.Base, abstract.Model):
    id = mapped_column(sqltypes.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    ...
    student_id = mapped_column(schema.ForeignKey('students.id'), nullable=False)
    student = relationship('Student', back_populates='homeworks')
    tasks = relationship('Task', back_populates='homework', lazy='selectin')

class Exercise(abstract.Base, abstract.Model):
    id = mapped_column(sqltypes.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    ...
    tasks = relationship('Task', back_populates='exercise', lazy='selectin')

class Task(abstract.Base, abstract.Model):
    id = mapped_column(sqltypes.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    ...
    exercise_id = mapped_column(schema.ForeignKey('exercises.id'), nullable=False)
    homework_id = mapped_column(schema.ForeignKey('homeworks.id'), nullable=False)
    exercise = relationship('Exercise', back_populates='tasks')
    homework = relationship('Homework', back_populates='tasks')
```

I would appreciate some explanation. Thanks!